# ofstream output to same text file from multiple .cpp files of a single project

Tags: c++, file-io

Dear All: I have a C++ project (in Visual Studio 2008) that comprises of header.h, source_1.cpp file that contains main() and source_2.cpp file.

At certain points in the program, I need to output some intermediate results into a text file, say, "output.txt". The thing is, I am unable to do this. That is, I am unable to output results into the same "output.txt" file from both source_1.cpp and source_2.cpp. I have been using ofstream for my write-to-file operations.

For instance, in source_1.cpp, I have said

```
ofstream ofile("output.txt");
```

and later in the code I would say,

```
ofile<<"Result of intermediate calculation are "<<intermediate_result<<endl;
```

to store the result into output.txt.

In source_2.cpp, it turns out I cannot define

```
extern ofstream ofile("output.txt");
```

(Error that same object has been defined in more than one place.)

I then tried saying in source_2.cpp

```
ofstream ofile_2("output.txt");//Note ofile_2 which is different from ofstream ofile in source_1.cpp
```

However, use of ofile_2 in source_2.cpp ends up erasing any previous output to the file written by ofile in source_1.cpp.

Should I be using something other than ofstream in order to write to the same file from two different .cpp files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way: Pass a instance of type `ostream&` to all clients which need to output the result. I recommend to resist the temptation to define a global static `ostream` objects visible to anybody...

Comment: Yes, passing by reference the ofstream object proved sufficient for my purposes.

Comment: NOT the best way. See Björn Pollex answer. Open the file with `ios::append`.

Answer (score 2):

The core of the problem is that you use two different file-handles to write to the same file. This is no problem if you do this sequentially. If you want to append to a file, you have to open it like this:

```
std::ofstream file("output.txt", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app)
```

This will tell the `ofstream` to append to the file.

In order to avoid naming conflicts between compilation units you can use [namespaces](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/).

Answer (score 1):

Every time you construct the `ofstream` with the same filename string, it will overwrite what was already there.

Encapsulate the `ofstream` in a class which constructs it once and then write to it from your other classes using members on a globally-accessible instance of this wrapper class.  This class could call `open()` on the first requested write, if you don't always want to write this file out.

Or (quicker but messy) just declare an `ofstream` at global scope for all to use.

I would not normally encourage globally-visible data in any form, but logfiles are one case where this makes sense.

You probably need to implement a mutex to mediate concurrent writes. Another argument for encapsulating the `ofstream` in a `FileWriter` class or similar. If you don't do this, you could find data from one thread confusingly interleaved with that from another thread.

If you expect your logging needs to become more complex you could consider [log4cpp](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/) rather than invest increasing amounts of time in this peripheral area of your logic.

Comment: Yes, I will try defining ofstream ofile() in header.h and including this header.h in both source_1.cpp and source_2.cpp. Hopefully that should do the trick...Thx.

Comment: @Tryer - that probably won't link.  You need to declare it once and define it in only one of the code files for linkage to not find dups.